# Is it a reasonable expectation to ask the interviewer to cover the travel costs

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, software-industry

I'm being asked to go to an interview overseas. The company agreed to cover the relocation costs if I get the job, but they didn't mention anything about the travel costs. My travel costs to the interview would be very high: flight from and to the location, hotel for a day, travel costs to the airport (the closest airport is 200km from where I live) and from the airport to the hotel.

Would it be reasonable for me to ask them to cover those costs?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Yes, the company knows that I'm not a local

Comment: @thelmuxkriovar I would be wary of a company that *didn't* offer to pay for your interview travel costs. If they have any experience with international candidates, they would would offer without you even having to ask. If they don't know that, then I would be suspicious.

Comment: It would be **bizarre** if they did not pay for your travel costs to the interview.  Indeed, it is almost certainly just some sort of scam.  They should **supply the travel tickets** for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would it be reasonable for me to ask them to cover those costs?

It's perfectly reasonable to ask if they will cover your expenses.

The company already knows that you are not local. If the company really wants you to interview in person, I would expect them to be willing to cover the cost for doing so. They may even offer their corporate travel department to help make arrangements for you.

But even if they decline to cover your costs, they won't think you unreasonable by asking about it.

Just ask before you commit to the interview, and hope they agree. Be ready with what you will do in the off chance that they decide not to cover the costs.

Comment: This assumes you ask before the interview. Asking after you have made the trip is likely to look bad and be denied since they never budgeted for it before you showed up and asked.

Answer (score 3):

> Would it be reasonable for me to ask them to cover those costs?

It would make sense to ask for such, as they are the ones requiring you to travel over there. At least it is not something outrageous to ask.

I suggest you write them an email inquiring about this situation, explaining to them (like you did here) if that would be possible. Try to keep it brief and simple, explaining that you will have to cover several expenses with your travel.

If you do, make sure you already have your trip planned ahead so you can answer them the details if they agree to cover that. Have some backup options for hotels etc., so they can authorize the one they consider better. It could also be the case that they already considered picking you up on the airport or probably host your stay at some hotel/house, so it will be better to ask to clear any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it be reasonable to ask them to cover those costs.  Given you have no guarantee to a job offer that you accept it is a lot of money.  It is an expense to them and you have to pay it out of taxed money.

Ask if they have a preferred hotel as they probably have a corporate rate with some local motels.

My experience is the travel cost covered is common for professionals.